# Split a scala list into n interleaving lists

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Given a `List` such as

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

what is the best way to split it into n sub-lists, putting items into each list in a round-robin fashion?

e.g. if n = 3, the result should be

```
List(List(1, 4, 7), List(2, 5), List(3, 6))
```

I thought there would be a method in the collections API to do this, but I can't seem to find it.

Bonus points for classy one-liners ;)

Comment: A similar question, using Streams: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115345/split-a-stream-in-many

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
scala> def round[T](l: List[T], n: Int) = (0 until n).map{ i => l.drop(i).sliding(1, n).flatten.toList }.toList
round: [T](l: List[T], n: Int)List[List[T]]

scala> round((1 to 7).toList, 3)
res4: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 4, 7), List(2, 5), List(3, 6))
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple one-liner:

```
scala> List.range(1, 10)
res11: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

scala> res11.grouped(3).toList.transpose
res12: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 4, 7), List(2, 5, 8), List(3, 6, 9))
```

Unfortunately it won't work when your list isn't *transposeable*.

```
scala> List.range(1, 8).grouped(3).toList.transpose
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: transpose requires all collections have the 
same size
```

You can use the following method to make it *transposeable*, and then apply the above approach.

```
scala> def extend[A](xs: List[A], c: Int): List[Option[A]] = {
     |   val n = Stream.iterate(c)(c +).find(_ >= xs.length).get
     |   xs.map(Some(_)).padTo(n, None)
     | }
extend: [A](xs: List[A], c: Int)List[Option[A]]

scala> List.range(1, 8)
res13: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

scala> extend(res13, 3).grouped(3).toList.transpose.map(_.flatten)
res14: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 4, 7), List(2, 5), List(3, 6))
```

Put together:

```
scala> def round[A](xs: List[A], c: Int) = {
     |   val n = Stream.iterate(c)(c +).find(_ >= xs.length).get
     |   val ys = xs.map(Some(_)).padTo(n, None)
     |   ys.grouped(c).toList.transpose.map(_.flatten)
     | }
round: [A](xs: List[A], c: Int)List[List[A]]

scala> round(List.range(1, 10), 3)
res16: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 4, 7), List(2, 5, 8), List(3, 6, 9))

scala> round(List.range(1, 8), 3)
res17: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 4, 7), List(2, 5), List(3, 6))
```

Comment: `ys.grouped(3)` is it a typo?

Comment: @senia, why would that be a typo?

Comment: You'll get `OutOfMemoryError` with `round(list, 0)`.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. The function isn't completely fool-proof.

Comment: All excellent answers, guys. Everybody gets an upvote! Thanks for showing me how to use transpose. That's the method I was looking for. But after a lot of consideration, @senia gets the tick for the classiest one-liner!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about making it round robin you can do:

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
list.grouped(Math.ceil(list.size / 3))
```