# Transpose on infinite stream loops forever

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation, scala-collections

Consider the following:

```
Stream.continually(List(1,2,3)).transpose
```

You would expect to get something equivalent to:

```
Stream(
  Stream.continually(1),
  Stream.continually(2),
  Stream.continually(3)
)
```

However, the upper construct loops infinitely. Is there a workaround for this? Is this to be considered a bug?

Question came up discussing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17115799/1149944).

**EDIT**

I know that a function like this writable, see the following example. But is there something in the library?

```
def myTranspose[A,B](in: Stream[A])
     (implicit asTraversable: A => GenTraversableOnce[B]): Stream[Stream[B]] = {
  val len = asTraversable(in.head).size

  for (i <- (0 until len).toStream)
    yield in.map(el => asTraversable(el).toIndexedSeq(i))
}
```

Comment: You'd probably want to define `transpose` the way Haskell's `Data.List` does it. Indeed, `transpose . repeat $ [1,2,3]` does what roughly you'd expect in Haskell. On the downside, the length of the resulting list is unknowable in Haskell, because `transpose` explicitly tries to deal with ragged lists of lists in a friendly manner. Given that Scala seems content to just throw an exception in those cases, its lazy implementation could easily assume that the input is uniformly shaped and provide a known length. Note that your version takes quadratic time in the number of elements you demand.